# How to get rid of ViewState Error

Tags: jsf, primefaces, viewstate, omnifaces

I used omnifaces to handle Redirect problem After Session Expired at PrimeFaces and it works very well. The problem is when I try to relogin after session timeout occurs and it directs me to login page, I come across with the following error.

After clicking F5, or reloading page that error disapperas and it directs me to homePage. The problem is I come across with this error after session expires and when I click an ajax button.Afterwards, it directs me to login Page. After I write username / password and click login button I come across with the ViewState Error a blank page which gives me the following message.

I would be so glad if you can help me.

Best Regards
Alper Kopuz

Error :

339983964997632919:6839730696265126459